# creating random numbers excluding all values in a list

Tags: python, random

I need to create random numbers in python.
But it should ignore all the values stored in a 2-d list and it should be within a specified range.

```
def load_food():
    global food_status, fx, fy
    exclude = list(chain.from_iterable(arr))
    if not food_status:
        fx = random.choice([j for j in range(0, 69) if j not in exclude])
        fy = random.choice([j for j in range(0, 69) if j not in exclude])
        screen.blit(food, (fx * 10, fy * 10))
        food_status = True
    else:
        screen.blit(food, (fx * 10, fy * 10))
```

once i gone with the above code ,it raised a run time error like

````
 File "C:\Users\SARIN ALEXANDER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\random.py", line 290, in choice
    raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence') from None
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use import random and create a function to check if the generated number is in the list, like this:

```
from random import randint

def my_custom_random():
    exclude=[2,5,7]
    randInt = randint(0,9)
    return my_custom_random() if randInt in exclude else randInt 

print(my_custom_random())
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by first flattening your 2-d list, then using the built in random.randrange:

```
from random import randrange

ignores = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6]
]

flat_ignores = [n for i in ignores for n in i]

nums = [randrange(0, 101, 2)  # get even pseudo-random number between 0 and 100, inclusive
        for i in range(10)  # repeat it 10 times
        if i not in flat_ignores  # and exclude bad numbers
        ]

for num in nums:
    print(num)
```

Returning:

```
36
34
34
36
```